# Require_once external vars and share those with other funcions in a php class

Tags: php, class, require-once

I have an external file with some vars to require in my php class and share those with all functions of my class:

vars.inc:

```
<?php
 $a = 1;
?>
```

class.php:

```
<?php
 class A{
  public function __construct(){
   require_once("vars.inc");
  }
  public function aB{
   echo $a;
  }
 }
?>
```

but it doesn't work: the $a var is undefined

how can I do?

thanks all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variables in a function only exist in local scope, unless you assign them to class variables.

For example, if you had this in your included page:

```
<?php
$myvariable = 'hello';
?>
```

Then your class should use the `$this` to assign it to a class variable.

myvariable = $myvariable;
      }

      public function aB{
       echo $myvariable;
      }

     }

    ?>

See the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) for more information about variable scope.

Comment: thanks, it works, however we have to retrieve var trough $this->var. Hi!

Answer (score 0):

It's a scope issue. Maybe this will be better:

```
<?php
 class A{
  protect $a;
  public function __construct(){
   require_once("vars.inc");
   $this->a = $a;

  }
  public function aB{
   echo $this->a;
  }
 }
?>
```

Comment: -1. Not only does this not work ($a disappears after __construct() occurs), but it encourages poor use of globals. The included page inherits the scope of where it's included, unless you define functions in the included page in which case the functions are global. Also, no need to downrate my comment.

Comment: You were quick to downvote. If you would have waited you would have seen me expand my answer and provide a better alternative.

Comment: But your initial code is wrong. When you require in the __construct it becomes a local variable of the construct. For your first code to work the vars.inc file would have to be required outside of the class

Answer (score 0):

That is generally a bad practice. Either give the variables to the class through the constructor or the methods, or create a Static class that holds the variables or globally accessible variable that will hold those values. It depends on your code and exactly you are trying to do.